# Checkbox type conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Visual studio 2010 with C#.

I have a problem, on one of my ascx pages I created a checkbox column like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Beetald">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectallTeachers" class="selectallTeachers" onclick="javasctipt:SelectheaderCheckboxesTeacher();" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkPaid" class="caseTeacher" name="caseTeacher" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I have created the javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Select/Deselect checkboxes based on header checkbox
    function SelectheaderCheckboxesTeacher() {
        if ($("#selectallTeachers").val() == 'on') {
            $('.caseTeacher').attr('checked', 'checked');
            $("#selectallTeachers").val('off');
        }
        else if ($("#selectallTeachers").val() == 'off') {
            $('.caseTeacher').removeAttr("checked");
            $("#selectallTeachers").val('on');
        }

        $(".caseTeacher").click(function () {
            if ($(".caseTeacher").length == $(".caseTeacher:checked").length) {
                $("#selectallTeachers").attr("checked", "checked");
                $("#selectallTeachers").val('off');
            } else {
                $("#selectallTeachers").removeAttr("checked");
                $("#selectallTeachers").val('on');
            }
        });
    }
    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectallTeachers checkbox
    // and viceversa   
</script>
```

For a buttonclick event I written this:

```
protected void btnDeleteSelectedMessages_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (currentGridView == null)
        setCurrentGridView();

    //controleer voor elke rij welke checkbox is geselecteerd
    foreach (GridViewRow row in currentGridView.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkPaid");
        Guid messageID = (Guid)currentGridView.DataKeys[row.DataItemIndex].Value;

        //als de checkbox is geselecteerd het bericht verwijderen
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        {
            if (currentGridView.ID.Equals("Messages"))
                b.BussinesMessageReceiver.DeleteMessageReceiver(messageID, MessageBoxPerson);
            else if (currentGridView.ID.Equals("MessagesSent"))
                b.BussinesMessage.DeleteMessageSender(messageID);
            else //MessagesDeleted
                b.BussinesMessage.DeleteMessage(messageID, (Page.Server.MapPath("~/Upload/") + messageID));
            continue;
        }
    }
    btnDeleteSelectedMessages.Enabled = false;
    selectLocation.Visible = false;
    clearSelectedMessageSession();

    //Update the GridView
    BindGridView();
}
```

It shows an error on the line

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkPaid");
```

because I have created by input type not directly by checkbox.

Comment: why can't you use check boxes instead of inputs?

Comment: It would be better if you specify what type of error it is showing.

Comment: What type does `row.FindControl("chkBoxDelete");` actually return?

Comment: I cant use directly Check box control i want to use the class attribute whick is not supported by it.

Comment: @ ChrisF  row.FindControl("chkBoxDelete"); where chkBoxDelete was a Check box control.

Comment: Why don't you use the asp:Checkbox instead?
You can use the CssClass property.

Answer (score 1):

An `input type="checkbox"` is not a [`CheckBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.aspx). So you should cast it to [`HtmlInputCheckBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputcheckbox%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (or use a `CheckBox`) instead.

```
var cb = (HtmlInputCheckBox)row.FindControl("chkPaid");
```

Comment: It also gives me red line under (HtmlInputCheckBox)

Comment: Then add `using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls`. I thought it would be clear which control i meant since i've provided a link.

Comment: Still i have the same problem     Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox'.                        I changed the cade as..                                                                   var cb = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox)row.FindControl("chkBoxDelete");

Comment: The _same problem_? I thought your first exception was that you cannot cast from the html-input to an ASP.NET-Checkbox control. Now the exception is that it cannot be casted from `CheckBox` to `HtmlInputCheckBox`. You also have changed your question. Now the ID of the "checkbox" is `chkPaid` instead of `chkBoxDelete`. What is correct?

Comment: Yes the problem is solved but though the Button is not working properly.   Now what is happening is that on first time clicking on the button it deletes the selected row but second or after that any time clicking on it the button is not working.